# Why I can't convert a String to int?

Tags: java, string, int

I'm very new in Java. I've a problem.
I have the String currentTime with a value of the current time like this: "2204201810".
I want to convert this String to an Integer.
The Error is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2204201804"

But I don't know why Java can't convert it! I mean the String contains just Numbers not more.

Here is my code:

```
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
String currentTime = df.format(now.getTime());

currentTime = currentTime.replace(".", "");
currentTime = currentTime.replace(" ", "");
currentTime = currentTime.replace(":", "");
try {
    int currentTimeInt = Integer.valueOf(currentTime);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    //Error
}
```

Comment: Did you check the content of `currentTime`? I doubt it has the content/format you expect

Comment: Print the string before & after replacing, you may be skipping some character that doesn't convert to `int`

Comment: I am not sure how the answer below worked.  When running this code `System.out.println(currentTime);` the output is `4/22/201042AM`, which to the best of my knowledge, cannot get turned into a int, long, or BigInteger.

Comment: @hooknc, then you have different locale settings in your OS, which use slashes instead of dots, commas, or colons, and also appends AM/PM in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are trying to convert to `int` (2204201804) exceeds the maximum integer capacity, which is 2147483647 in Java. Try using `long` instead. Or maybe even `BigInteger`, depending on your needs.

Comment: No problem. Can you accept the answer as the correct one?